What is the difference between `HighLevelSynthesis` and `UnrollCustomDefinitions` qiskit transpilation passes?
The doc for UnrollCustomDefinitions indicates :
Unrolls instructions with custom definitions.

Parameters
    equivalence_library (EquivalenceLibrary) – The equivalence library which will be used by the BasisTranslator pass. (Instructions in this library will not be unrolled by this pass.)
    basis_gates (Optional[list[str]]) – Target basis names to unroll to, e.g. ['u3', 'cx']. Ignored if target is also specified.

And looking at the code, it indeed seems to replace gates that are not in the equivalence library and that are not in the basis_gates, by "unrolling their definitions". This is done by looking at the .definition attribute (if it exists) for the operations to replace.
The doc for HighLevelSynthesis indicates :
Synthesize higher-level objects and unroll custom definitions.
The input to this pass is a DAG that may contain higher-level objects, including abstract mathematical objects (e.g., objects of type LinearFunction), annotated operations (objects of type AnnotatedOperation), and custom gates.
In the most common use-case when either basis_gates or target is specified, all higher-level objects are synthesized, so the output is a DAGCircuit without such objects. More precisely, every gate in the output DAG is either directly supported by the target, or is in equivalence_library.
...

I understand that the HighLevelSynthesis pass tries to synthetize more that custom gates. And I see that it also tries to use the .definition attribute of these custom gates.
Is it right to say that the UnrollCustomDefinitions logic is included in HighLevelSynthesis ?
And that the UnrollCustomDefinitions should not be necessary if there is already a HighLevelSynthesis pass in the transpilation stages ?

Yes, it's correct.
